# cv2.imshow() function restart python shell without showing any error program stops

Tags: python, shell, opencv

I have written simple python code

```
    import cv2
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    try: 
      for i in range(10):
         print i
         _,f=cam.read()
         cv2.imshow('f',f)
         k=cv2.waitKey(1)

    catch:
      print 'error'
```

this code only display 0 and quit working further python shell restarts 
I am working with Respberry PI with python 2.7.9
and Opencv 2.4.9.1

When I remove cv2.imshow() line then code works fine. and it prints 0 to 9 all digits. It means cam is connected and opencv even reading images from camera but the issue is with displaying images

Could any one find similar problem before or have any solution? please share thanks

Comment: Try with : `k=cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: I have even tried with this

Comment: Acttually I have a full code working on my laptop windows, working perffectly fine. But the issue is in respberry PI when I run on PI it quit without showing any error I even used without waitkey() function but no Window displays. In opencv Cv atleast a window appears without waitkey function but It hangs but in PI no windows appears I have created this piece of code to just check if simple python camread works or not in resp PI but problem is same

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not `cv2.imshow()`. your problem is `cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0).`
opencv has a problem finding the camera within raspberry pi!
the `imshow()` does work and noramly would give you the problem. To be honest i am suprised your try/catch work, this is not how you write a try/catch in python, the proper way is :

```
try:
    peace of the code that might throw an exception
except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Note: *your code did not work for me before i changed the try/catch!*

now Back to the problem, since the image can not show it will tell you your image length/width is 0.
to solve this is a litel bit long, however someone allready created a working code for that [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/30/accessing-the-raspberry-pi-camera-with-opencv-and-python/)

Note: you will need to use `picamera` to use raspbery pi camera!

opencv does not take it's pride handeling a camera, other packages do.

Note: in rasbery pi you need to add () before your print such as `print (i)`
      sometimes it can create you an error